# How to disable/enable sorting while editing in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have a editTable like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat='guest in guestList | orderBy:orderByField:reverseSort'>
   <td><span ng-show='!guest.isedit'>{{guest.firstname}}</span><span ng-show='guest.isedit'><input type="text" ng-model='guest.firstname'/></span></td>
    <td><span ng-show='!guest.isedit'><a href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click='editGuest(guest)'><i class="material-icons">mode_edit</i></a></span><span ng-show='guest.isedit'><button ng-click='contactUpdate(guest)'>OK</button></span></td>
</tr>
```

in my controller:

```
$scope.editGuest = function(guest){
        delete $scope.orderByField;  
        guest.isedit = true;   
    };
$scope.contactUpdate = function(guest){
       //Save the change then put the order back to re-order the table
      $scope.orderByField = 'firstname';
}
```

As you can see, this is a editable table, if I click edit, the table becomes editable. I want to disable the sort when editing, until user finish editing and hit the OK button(Which already saved in the server), then I will re-order with new data. The problem is for the first time I fire editGuest(guest),it will still jump. Is there any way I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a different ng-model on your input box like this :

```
<tr ng-repeat='guest in guestList | orderBy:orderByField:reverseSort'>
   <td>
       <span ng-show='!guest.isedit'>{{guest.firstname}}</span>
       <span ng-show='guest.isedit'><input type="text" value="{{ guest.firstname }}" ng-model='firstname'/></span>//I have set the value to the guest's firstname to default the name when the input box becomes active. You can also use ng-init to achieve it.
</td>
    <td>
        <span ng-show='!guest.isedit'><a href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click='editGuest(guest)'><i class="material-icons">mode_edit</i></a></span>
        <span ng-show='guest.isedit'><button ng-click='contactUpdate(firstname)'>OK</button></span></td>
</tr>
```

In your Controller :

```
$scope.contactUpdate(guest, name){
    guest.firstname = name;
    name = '';//EDIT
}
```

Comment: I think firstname is not in `guestList` so it will be same for all `<tr>`'s. Don't you think that this should be unique for each row ?

Comment: Otherwise you have to pass guest in `contactUpdate` function and after saving clear `firstname` value.

Comment: @shyammakwana.me yup you're right. I am passing the guest in the update function so that shouldnt be an issue. I should clear the firstname after setting it

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove binding first for this.

Create clone of `guestList` object and do the editing operation on it.

once it is done assign the clone object back to `guestList`.

e.g.

var dummyGuestList = angular.copy(guestList)

//some operation on `dummyGuestList` ;

```
guestList = dummyGuestList //assign bacl again
```